# How can I get rid of a border on my responsive chessboard grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following pattern, and it is quite responsive, no matter how I zoom in or change the width of the page squares stays the same size, the only way these squares change in size is by changing the height of the page. and that's what I want.

[image: chess board with css]

I achieved this by making the width and height proportional to the height of the page, using `vh` units, and adding these squares to a CSS grid.

The problem is the squares in the middle of the image appear to have a border, whereas I don't want a border. This is what I want, instead:

[image: blended]

I tried padding the squares to the right or making a white border around them, but both approaches affected the responsiveness of the squares.

How can I blend those squares with the white background without affecting the responsiveness?

Is there a way I can reduce the amount of code required for the '.rect:nth-child' section?

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;   
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.left{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 45vh;
    height:100vh;
    
}

.design{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(9, 1fr); 
}

.rect{
    background-color: white;
    width: calc(100vh / 9);
    height: calc(100vh / 9);
}

.rect:nth-child(1){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.rect:nth-child(2){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}
.rect:nth-child(3){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}
.rect:nth-child(4){
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}
.rect:nth-child(5){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
}
.rect:nth-child(6){
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-start: 4;
}
.rect:nth-child(7){
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-start: 6;
}
.rect:nth-child(8){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 7;
}
.rect:nth-child(9){
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 8;
}
.rect:nth-child(10){
    grid-column-start: 4;
    grid-row-start: 8;
}
.rect:nth-child(11){
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 9;
}
.rect:nth-child(12){
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 9;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="left">
        <div class='design'>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>
            <div class="rect"></div>  
        </div> 
    </div>

    <div class="right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML to your question. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Have you tried this approach? http://cassidybrooke.net/chess/

Comment: @ManojKumar the problem is not with the pattern, the problem is in the blending.

Comment: But I cannot reproduce the results as in the image. Have you switched colors or something? Also it is not perfectly responsive at all. In smaller screens, the squares are very small.  https://nimb.ws/QEV3eU

Comment: @ManojKumar that's so strange. try runing it on a browser.

Comment: @awovunetux Do you think I run it on a potato right now? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problems

> *"How can I blend those squares with the white background without affecting the responsiveness?"*
>
> *"Is there a way I can reduce the amount of code required for the '`.rect:nth-child`' section?"*

In order to cleanly resolve all issues, one must consider that the most direct and simplest solutions will most likely yield the best results as well as provide a stable base to which one can expand upon in the future. Using CSS grid for a simple design is over complicated, unnecessary, and will become problematic (it appears it already is -- hence this post).

Having said that, the pattern can be duplicated using:
  1 `<table>`, 1 `<tbody>`, 9 `<tr>`, and 36 `<td>`
    ***or***
  tags assigned: `display:` `table;`, `table-row-group;`, `table-row;`, and `table-cell;`

- **Reply to the first question:** Tables have two ways to eliminate or blend all borders on and within itself:

  `table { border-collapse: collapse; }`
  ***or***
  `table { border-collapse: separate;`⃰  `border-spacing: 0; }`
  `table, td { border: 0; }`

  The second option is for more granular control like using `border-radius` or narrowing cells by negative `border-spacing` values, etc. Applying `border: 0;` to any other type of tag does not guarantee a seamless design (table behavior and style has been perfected and honed for 25+ years).
   ⃰ <sup>Default that can be omitted under normal circumstances.</sup>
- **Reply to the second question:** Use a table design -- refer to previous information concerning tables.

  OP's CSS.....: 16 rulesets / 35 properties
  ***VS***
  Answer's CSS: 6 rulesets / 15 properties (less code)

---

### Update

> *"...  <del>i</del>  `I` am trying to keep the design within the  <del>view port</del>  `viewport` without any scrolling."*

- **Solution to the first requirement:** Focus on how the parent tag occupies the viewport. Which would be difficult considering the OP's layout (ie `.design`). But with a table layout we can define dimensions by content:

  ```
  table { table-layout: fixed; ... }
  td { width: 11vh; height: 11vh; padding: 0 ... }
  ```

  `table-layout: fixed` will force the table's width to conform to the width of each column. So here we have the dimensions of `44vh` x `99vh` which is well within the confines of the viewport. Note that `100vh` is not used yet it is apparent in the demo that everything is edge to edge. It's never going to be precise from browser to browser, device to device, etc. -- hence `11vh` will suffice rather than a length that actually exceeds the borders of visibility (ie `calc(100vh / 9)`)
- **Solution to the second requirement:** A complete and efficient way to eliminate scrolling is:

  ```
  body { overflow: hidden; }
  ```

---

#### Demo

The following demo is 100% responsive vertically. It has no scrollbars and it is perfectly edge to edge. Also the color pattern is how it is posted in OP's screenshot without any unseemly borders. Moreover, it will not lose its structural integrity at extreme dimensions (ex. OP's code will separate and loose group cohesiveness as viewport height decreases).

```css
:root,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font: 700 2vh/1 Consolas;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

main {
  width: 99vh;
  height: 99vh;
  background: white;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: -8px 0 auto 0;
}

td {
  width: 11vh;
  height: 11vh;
  padding: 0;
  background: white;
}

.b {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
        <td></td>
        <td class='b'></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</main>
```

Comment: vw would never work in my case, since i am trying to keep the design within the view port without any scrolling.